# How to specify User Id/password with integrated security?

Tags: sql-server

I know that integrated security is the option to use in a SQL connection string for windows authentication (since we dont have sql authentication), but suppose I want someone else to be able to connect t to the database server (datasource) and database, and I'm giving them the windows account and password used to access the database server (runas different user SSMS)

How can they specify a userid and password while also using integrated security for windows authentication?

Something like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=UserDomainName\UserName;Password=myPassword;
```

But from what I read, integrated security ignores the userid/password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can't... that isn't how Integrated Security works.

You can use 'run-as' (hold shift, right-click SSMS icon, select 'run as different user') if you are using a client app like SSMS, or Impersonation if you are doing this in some code you control.

Comment: How can I do the impersonation in the connection string?

Comment: @Cataster You can't - that is not possible. Impersonation is a windows api call that lets you use another user context - so if you are doing this is an application you are writing, you can impersonate, then connect but you need to write code for this you can't just do it 'in the connection string'

Comment: Darn...you mentioned ”impersonation in some code we can control” could you elaborate? The person who wants to establish the connection but doesn't have access is hosting a .net application in the private cloud, and in order for users to be able to connect to this app (that establishes a connection to the database) they need to input their user id and password.  This creates a problem because we cant add everyone's ID to grant them database access, we need to to be able to do it with the windows service account ID to avoid this

Comment: @Cataster - so why don't you just grant the service account id access to the database... I don't think I understand your issue

Comment: Impersonation is certainly possible in a .net application, so he (person writing the .net app) can just impersonate the required account before doing the database call. That said, it sounds like you don't really want to do that, and you just want to give the service account permission to the database instead... Take a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes so the service account actually already is provisioned to access the database. Because its able to access the database server (runas SSMS), I sent it over to this person so he can establish the connection string with it. However, because the connection string requires windiws authentication (integrated security), we need to tell the connection string to use windows authentication of this service account

Comment: Yeah so you just need "Integrated Security=SSPI" in the connection string. That will use Integrated Security. Then any application running as that service account will be able to connect. He just needs to make sure his Service (or IIS App Pool or whatever) is running under the context of that service account and it will work.

Comment: So he just emailed me back to the suggestion of changing the service login, and said that he'll be running this from linux, not windows...lol this added another twist to the puzzle

Comment: It is possible to use Kerberos from Linux to authenticate to SQL with Integrated Authentication, however a bit more fiddley than a SO answer can cover... try sending him some articles like this one: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272546/Authenticate-Net-Core-client-of-SQL-Server-with-In

Comment: Looks like it requires docker, which we dont use

Comment: @Cataster No, it doesn't *require* docker, they just happen to set it up in Docker in that article... you can do the same thing on a normal linux host and it will work. Nothing "requires" docker, docker containers are just like tiny virtual machines

Comment: Just to confirm, kinit, kdc, etc...from the article, these are commands/artifacts Not related to docker, and we run/create as well on our linux box, correct?

Comment: man I just received a notification that this question became ”popular” and reading my comments here compared to my experience today, ooft, I sounded dumb 3 years ago LOL

Comment: Thats normal - you'll say the same thing in 3 years about your code/comments today! :P one of the fun things about programming

Comment: Gotta love the thrill of it